# Typescript - How to automatically infer the type of Union variable

Tags: typescript

Given my mapping here why is typescript unable to infer the type of state automatically?

Shouldn't my FormIdToFormValues be enough for typescript to know what is going on?

```js
export enum FORM_ID {
  STEP_1 = 'step1',
  STEP_2 = 'step2',
  STEP_3 = 'step3',
}

export type FormIdToFormValues = {
  [FORM_ID.STEP_1]: Step1FormValues;
  [FORM_ID.STEP_2]: Step2FormValues;
  [FORM_ID.STEP_3]: Step3FormValues;
};

type Step1FormValues = {
    a: string
}
type Step2FormValues = {
    b: string
}

type Step3FormValues = {
    c: string
}


// Define the type of the state parameter
type StateType<F extends FORM_ID> = FormIdToFormValues[F];

export const getNextRoute = <F extends FORM_ID>(formId: F, state: StateType<F>) => {
  switch (formId) {
    case FORM_ID.STEP_1:
      // Error happens here -----
      if (state?.a) {
        return '/step-3';
      }
      return '/step-2';
    default:
      return '/';
  }
};
```

The error in detail is:

```
Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Step1FormValues | Step2FormValues | Step3FormValues'.
  Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Step2FormValues'.
```

Comment: ① Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] without reference to private or undeclared values and types.  This will make it easier for us to copy and paste it into our own IDEs, investigate, try out fixes, and suggest something useful to you. ② Currently control flow analysis (like `switch`/`case`) doesn't play nicely with generic type parameters (like `F`).  You'll want to refactor to make the function non-generic, or to avoid control-flow logic.  Either way is probably possible, but without a [mre] I'm not able to easily demonstrate this.

Comment: Have updated the enum, also the same problem occurs with if statements

Comment: I'm sorry but this is still not a [mre]; please copy and paste your code into a standalone IDE and fix any errors unrelated to your question  If I do that, my IDE complains that it has no idea what `Step1FormValues` is, for instance.  Is it clear now what a [mre] is and how you can get one?

Comment: Apologies I've upated the code to be easily copied

Comment: Thanks.  As mentioned, the issue is that control-flow analysis doesn't work with generic type parameters. Either you should make the function non-generic [like this](https://tsplay.dev/wXyG9N), or you should make the generic implementation use indexing for control flow, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mLrbZw).  Do either of those meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Wonderful, the first option seems better in my opinion, it would be nice to know why generic type params don't have the same control-flow analysis. Regardless thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in TypeScript, [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) type parameters are currently not affected by [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).  So inside the `case` block in

```
const getNextRoute = <F extends FORM_ID>(formId: F, state: StateType<F>) => {
  switch (formId) {
    case FORM_ID.STEP_1:
      if (state?.a) { // error
        return '/step-3';
      }
      return '/step-2';
    default:
      return '/';
  }
};
```

the type of the `formId` *value* has been narrowed from the generic type parameter `F` to `F & FORM_ID.STEP_1`, the type parameter `F` itself is unaffected.  Thus the compiler cannot verify that `state` of type `StateType<F>` can be treated like `StateType<FORM_ID.STEP_1>`, and it fails.

---

This might seem like a strange limitation, but it turns out to be difficult to implement the desired behavior correctly.  Let's imagine the easiest possible case; a function like

```
function f<T extends string | number>(a: T, b: T) { 
  return (typeof a === "string") ? b.toUpperCase() : b.toFixed() // error!
  //                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~ <---> ~~~~~~~
}
```

The compiler complains that `b` is still `string | number` and thus is not known to have `toUpperCase` or `toFixed`.  It's obvious that checking `a` should also affect `b`, right?

Wrong. `T` is not required to be a subtype of `string` or a subtype of `number`; it could also be a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  Like this:

```
f(Math.random() < 0.99 ? "" : 0, 0); // okay
```

The first argument is of type `"" | 0`, so `T` is inferred to be `"" | 0`.  This is accepted, since `"" | 0` is a subtype of `string | number`.  Then the second parameter argument is checked, and sure enough, `0` is also a valid value of type `"" | 0`.  And if `T` is `"" | 0`, then it is quite possible for `a` to be a `string` while `b` is a `number` or vice versa.  Indeed this call has a 99% chance of calling `toUpperCase()` on `0` at runtime and causing a runtime error.  Oops.

So any change to incorporate generic type parameters with control flow analysis will need some careful thought.  There are various open feature requests to do that; the most relevant ones for your example code is [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) and [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808).  If either or both of these were implemented, your code might start working as-is.  But for now it's not part of the language and you need to work around it.

---

By far the easiest workaround is just to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const getNextRoute = <F extends FORM_ID>
  (
    formId: F, state: StateType<F>
  ) => {
  switch (formId) {
    case FORM_ID.STEP_1:
      if ((state as Step1FormValues)?.a) { // assert
        return '/step-3';
      }
      return '/step-2';
    default:
      return '/';
  }
};
```

Here we've stopped trying to have the compiler follow the logic, and just *tell* the compiler what's going on.  This means we  have to be more careful since the compiler probably won't notice if our assertion is incorrect.

If you *do* want the compiler to follow your logic, then you'll need to refactor to either stop using a generic function, or stop using control flow analysis.

---

One approach is to give up on generics so that you can use control flow analysis.  This is viable only if your function does not actually *need* to be generic, such as if the return type does not depend on the inputs.  Since your output is just `string` no matter what, you should be able to rewrite the call signature so that it is not generic.  Here's one way to do that:

```
type GetNextRouteParams =
  { [F in FORM_ID]: [formId: F, state: StateType<F>] }[FORM_ID];

/* type GetNextRouteParams = 
     [formId: FORM_ID.STEP_1, state: Step1FormValues] | 
    [formId: FORM_ID.STEP_2, state: Step2FormValues] | 
    [formId: FORM_ID.STEP_3, state: Step3FormValues]; */

const getNextRoute: (...args: GetNextRouteParams) => string =
  (formId, state) => {
    switch (formId) {
      case FORM_ID.STEP_1:
        if (state?.a) { // okay
          return '/step-3';
        }
        return '/step-2';
      default:
        return '/';
    }
  };
```

If you inspect the type of `GetNextRouteParams` you'll see that it's a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) corresponding to the desired sets of parameters you want `getNextRoute()` to accept.  We then give `getNextRoute`'s call signature a [rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) of that union of tuples, and suddenly the implementation works.

The compiler understands that it can treat the `formId` and `state` parameters as a [destructured discriminated union](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) and thus when the discriminant `formId` is checked, the type of `state` is narrowed accordingly.

---

If you can't give up generics then you could pursue giving up control flow narrowing, by refactoring your behavior so that the switching is replaced by indexing into an object.  This lets you use the support implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) to perform what looks like a single generic action.  For example:

```
const getNextRoute = <F extends FORM_ID>(formId: F, state: StateType<F>) => {
  const defaultCase = () => { return '/' };
  const cases: { [F in FORM_ID]: (state: StateType<F>) => string } = {
    [FORM_ID.STEP_1]: state => {
      if (state?.a) {
        return '/step-3'
      }
      return '/step2'
    },
    [FORM_ID.STEP_2]: defaultCase,
    [FORM_ID.STEP_3]: defaultCase
  }
  return cases[formId](state);
};
```

Here I've replaced the `switch`/`case` with an object named `cases` whose keys correspond to `formId` (of type `F`) and whose values are functions whose parameters correspond to `state` (of type `StateType<F>`).  Then by evaluating the single code block `cases[formId](state)`  the compiler understands that this is allowable.

This is a complicated refactoring and probably will confuse most people who read it... but if you do need generics (like if the return type of the function were also `SomeOtherType<F>`) and still want the compiler to follow your logic, this is currently the only way I know of for it to work.

---

So, there you go.  Generics and control flow analysis don't play nicely together; you can use one but not the other, or just give up entirely and use a type assertion.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.3.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg8gJQLIH0CSARKBvAUFKAZQBUBRABRQEYoBeKAcgGcAXYAByoYBp8izKAJjqNWHQTz4kKKAMwjmbdrMkBfXLhYBPdsFgB7AE4Q0AE2L6YRiADUAhgBswwJiLwEA2vGToMAOmlKKgBdAC4iJSorY3snFwBuPi9EVEwAgRRBMIjxaNtHZyZEz29U-0C5bMIlWTzYwsTVRM0dPWqOKOt6lzc+O3DWQwBLEABzXHVtXRz2QTqCnvp3KAAjAZZhsYmNKbaa+bjXJb4AY3XN8fUNFunquzZiVoAeGChgAA82EFNXUt8APhEeTMFgOhS8wWaJ30IFYUFGwBYADkPiwEPowGw4MNRiIXm9PqAfrAUgC+AAKPgEABm1jM4Rg3CgrHuwHCdwezxg-z4AEo6IDlkwAO5DFgnAAWUHJtOMZn5ywIJzsTD0fzSFSooSpBCgAHo9VBSIZDEYoBK7OxdLDzcBDHoALROp06ghDanSllsAD8fjsCtduvtLDAhhAjD1YnYDpUxV1BHU8YIwdD4YYkaUDokcYIpmA1LsYAcLG1SagKbDEYYcfUTWu1LAIBOLCGMKg1KexAJX2JgxGuIAPlBwBAVnb-uT+lBiEy1tOA8nEanpbt9B67HRaPQAER9sbb-ne1Z+Fj6ACqVrtAGEVcByfzwisT5Yhu9gKZ79tqeSkPcJX5DDsb59Age8oCeKAAAY-AAThgqAj23bcoHCSCmUg3koRhOEEWRVF0UxYAAEEmFVQw2FMPFXlRIlflJTAeQISl41lExTAZJkvTZCJWUeXQXkYqB+VoQU+BFMVJWlVj5RwHVlVVEkfA1DItUDd1pXJLioBVGZOhiBYmF5X1-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-rw8ybIjeLE3gHz3VQ98IvZBL-MuZYcu+Hs3yMaYKa2OCL22EwgKgA)

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't it know what type this is since I've passed it as a generic?

The problem is that TypeScript would need to support, for example, the case where `getNextRoute` is called like this:

```
var step2: Step2FormValues;
// ...
getNextRoute<FORM_ID.STEP_2 | FORM_ID.STEP_3>(FORM_ID.STEP_3, step2);
```

In other words: since the generic parameter `F` could be a *set* of enum values rather than *one specific* enum value, the type of `state` cannot be automatically narrowed based on the value of `formId`.

---

To successfully infer the subtype, one option is to turn the three Step types into a tagged union, and switch on the tag field (which I've called `id` in this example) instead of a separately passed parameter:

```
export enum FORM_ID {
  STEP_1 = 'step1',
  STEP_2 = 'step2',
  STEP_3 = 'step3',
}

type Step1FormValues = {
    id: FORM_ID.STEP_1;
    a: string;
}
type Step2FormValues = {
    id: FORM_ID.STEP_2;
    b: string;
}
type Step3FormValues = {
    id: FORM_ID.STEP_3;
    c: string;
}
type FormValues = Step1FormValues | Step2FormValues | Step3FormValues;

export const getNextRoute = (state: FormValues) => {
  switch (state?.id) {
    case FORM_ID.STEP_1:
      if (state.a) {
        return '/step-3';
      }
      return '/step-2';
    default:
      return '/';
  }
};
```